# Could not find or load main class test.Test

Tags: java

```
package test;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            System.out.print("Enter name to search");
            String name = sc.next();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE first_name = '" + name + "' ;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("Last_Name: " + rs.getString("last_name"));
                System.out.println("First_Name: " + rs.getString("first_name"));
                System.out.println("Email: " + rs.getString("email"));
                System.out.println("Phone: " + rs.getString("mobile_phone"));

            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.
     }
```

I imported jdbc.jar into the project library and still getting the error:

```
Could not find or load main class test.Test
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a compiler error, but like a runtime error. How are you starting your program?

Comment: I'm guessing you're running your program from the wrong folder.

Comment: I use NetBeans, I also tried in cmd javac but it gives the same error.

Comment: Try to  rebuild and make sure this class exists in the target directory.

Comment: Where did you save this .java file?

Comment: In the src folder of the project, when I try compiling using cmd I get this error: Class names, 'Test', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Comment: Why don't you answer what you're being asked: what command do you execute to get the above error message?

Comment: C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\RetCalc\Test\src>dir
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\RetCalc\Test\src>javac Test
error: Class names, 'Test', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\RetCalc\Test\src>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using some IDE? 
Your class is inside the "test" package, so if you want to execute your program directly from the command line, you should go into the parent folder of test, then launch:

> java test.Test

Comment: I removed it from the package and nothing has changed.

Comment: How do you execute your program? If it is outside the package, open the terminal in the same directory of your .class file, and simply launch java Test (the name of the class without the extension).

Comment: In the NetBeans project\src\Test.java , when I run it with F6 it says it can't find the class 'Test'. Then I try going to the src folder in cmd I run the command : "javac Test" and get the folowing "Class names, 'Test', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested ".

Comment: Did you remove the first line of your code: "package test;"? When you compile with javac, you must pass the filename including the extension, so it would be: "javac Test.java".

Comment: Yes I removed the "package test;".

Comment: Now it compiles, I needed to add the .java extension: javac Test.java.